# Why can I not use $this in function arguments default value

Tags: php, codeigniter, function

I trying to pass a parameter in codeigniter.

This works for me:

```
function the_kwarg($gender){
    $gender = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

However,i don't understand why this is wrong

```
function the_kwarg($gender=$this->uri->segment(3)){
    //$gender = $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

Why is it wrong to do it that way?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because functions can only accept scalar default values, it can't evaluate `$this` (or any variable) in that context.

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php):

> A function may define C++-style default values for scalar arguments.

And:

> The default value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a class member or a function call.

Answer (score 3):

Function arguments default values cannot be a dynamic expression, e.g.

```
function foo ($x = 1 + 1) { }
```

is illegal, because `1 + 1` is an expression. We all know the result is a constant `2`, but PHP isn't smart, and just sees an expression.

Answer (score 1):

While people already gave you correct answers, I can give you an example how to solve the problem:

```
function the_kwarg($gender = null){
    $gender = (!is_null($gender)) ? $gender : $this->uri->segment(3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the function like

```
function the_kwarg($gender){
echo $gender; // will echo male 
}

 // http://www.example.com/controller/the_kwarg/male
```

In CI the `uri segments` after the function name  are basically  the parameters of the function